# validate already created ipython notebook output with expected

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have created a report on ipython notebook with widgets embedded.I  want to validate the content of this created notebook as expected.
Some of the checks are :

1) When kernel loaded, I can see this output in cell1.

2) when I click on this widget button, I get the following output.

eg: I have created below notebook(just demo real notebook is big and heavy coded)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mbn2.png)

I want to validate the content and behavior of widgets(List of checks).

Comment: You can copy the content of the Notebook into a `.py` file, then run it as a Python script

Comment: I need to check the action of widgets as well which might not be possible with converting to .py( might be I don't know)